# Inserting row second time in a loop gives me error, I need to stop macro, save document and restart it to insert the next

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in excel that are searching for a value in a column and when it is found, it should insert a new, empty row and then continue to search for the next place to insert a new row.

It searches the cells in a column in a loop, it finds the value it's supposed to find and a new row is inserted. The loop resets and it searches the column again for a new value. However, when it finds this value, it does not give me a new row. An "out of memory" message pops up and the macro stops. At that time, I can't manually insert rows either untill I save my document. If I save it, I can re-run my macro and it runs one time without issues and then I get the same result.

I have tried all combinations in the recalculation-settings, I think. I have converted the whole code from using .Select, .Offset etc to use Cells() but the problem is the same. Only differense is that it runs a bit faster now.

This is a sample of the code giving me this issue:

```
Do While True
currentRow = 1
stringComparer = "PRM_" & prmNumber

Do While True
currentString = Cells(currentRow, parameterColumn)

If StrComp(currentString, stringComparer) = 0 Then
Cells(currentRow, parameterColumn).EntireRow.Insert
Exit Do
End If

currentRow = currentRow + 1
Loop

prmNumber = prmNumber + 1

Loop
```

Comment: When you are inserting rows, it is usually better to start from the bottom and work up so you do not skip rows. Seeing the relevant section of your code might have been considered important.

Comment: I have updated the question with a code sample. Why would inserting rows from the bottom help me? I think I know what you mean, and I can see why that might be a good idea, though everytime I insert a row I restart the macro from the top anyway so I don't skip anything. :)

Comment: You don't need to restart the macro from the top, either loop from the bottom as Jeeped said or only increment your counter when you do not insert. So If insert else increment end if

Comment: But it's not incrementing when I insert since I exit the loop when I insert, right? :o

Comment: Also: Tested to search from the bottom instead, it gives me that same error as soon as it tries to insert a row for the second time. . . :(

Why is it working again when I save the document? Can I make that happen in code? It feels like it's got to do with the calculation thing, like it's not updated that the document has more rows or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim parameterColumn As Integer
Dim prmNumber As Integer
Dim Match As Boolean
Match = False
parameterColumn = 1
currentRow = 1

currentString = Cells(currentRow, parameterColumn)

' loop until you reach the end of the data
Do While currentString <> ""
    'for each row, check for each of the parameters (I wasnt sure how many you have)
    For prmNumber = 1 To 10
        If StrComp(currentString, "PRM_" & CStr(prmNumber)) = 0 Then
           Match = True
        End If
    Next
    ' if there is a match, insert a row and add 2 to the current row (to include the inserted row)
    If Match Then
        Cells(currentRow, parameterColumn).EntireRow.Insert
        currentRow = currentRow + 2
    Else
    ' if there isnt a match, only add 1
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    End If
    Match = False
    currentString = Cells(currentRow, parameterColumn)
Loop
```